# deleted a now-inaccessible harddrive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios

When formatting my computer for Windows XP, there were two hard drives available to format.  I deleted the latter hard drive with 'L' option, thinking they would merge.  They didn't merge.  I deleted the primary hard drive, which XP boot-disk sometimes recognizes but cannot format.  Now I'm dual-booting XP & Ubuntu on the second (smaller) hard drive.  The problem is that bios doesn't appear to read the first hard drive correctly when BIOS has it 'on'.  (no ID) 
Another thing that occurred since deleting it is a message right after setup option and before dual-boot option:  'floppy diskette failure' or something like that.  That message doesn't seem to affect the performance though.  It sucks, but I'm hoping to find something for guiding me to recover the TB I actually *lost*.

Comment: Recovery software might be able to recover the data.  Please provide specific exact error messages.

Comment: It sounds to me like you deleted a partition, not a physical drive. Are there physically two hard drives or did you just see two drives listed in the setup menu? Also, do you have a floppy drive?

Answer (score 0):

You should try with another xp cd.May be you cd be corrupted or your hard disk is not properly attached or damaged.

Booting with other xp disk solved my problem.